# What happens if you use the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation of a non-WSS process to compute power spectral density?

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, fourier, stochastic

The Wiener–Khinchin theorem states that the power spectral density of a wide-sense stationary stochastic process can be obtained through the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation of the signal i.e.
$$ S(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} R(\tau) e^{-j \omega \tau} d\tau $$

I would like to find out what happens when I use this theorem for non-WSS signals?

To be specific, I want to assess the validity, for non-WSS, of a derivation  which uses this theorem to arrive to the conclusion that when two signals with phase noise are multiplied, the output phase noise $S_{\phi_{IF}}$ is related to the input phase noise $S_{\phi}$ by
$$
S_{\phi_{IF}}(f) = S_{\phi}(f) 4 \sin^2 (\frac{\alpha f}{2})
$$

I am aware of the more generally applicable approach for computing PSD through Fourier decomposition but it's a little difficult to apply to the above mentioned derivation.

Thank you.

Comment: For non-WSS signal, $R(\tau)$ does not exist. As the premise is not true, the theorem is not applicable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem

Comment: The autocorrelation function of _any_ process (whether WSS or not) is defined as $R_x(t_1, t_2) = E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ and is a function of _two_ variables. It is just that for WSS processes, $R_x(t_1, t_2)$ happens to depend only on $t_2-t_1$, and not upon the individual values of $t_1$ and $t_2$.  And so, setting $t_1=t, t_2 = t+\tau, t_2-t_1=\tau$, we arrive at the usual expression $R_X(\tau)=E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]$ for WSS processes.  So, please tell us what you mean by "the Fourier transform" of $R_x(t_1, t_2)$ of a nonWSS process. How is it defined? -1 pending edits.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. @DilipSarwate rather than having a formal definition, it is a signal I have captured with a radar receiver which I know to be non-stationary according to literature on phase-locked loop synthesisers. I have definitely computed its autocorrelation using MATLAB/Python although I have gone through theory that says the autocorrelation of a non-WSS signal doesn't exist.

Comment: The signal is likely stationary up to a certain capture length in time (in the short time frame)-- I assume you are dealing with phase noise effects which become non stationary as we approach the carrier (as would happen over long time intervals). If you include the specifics on the testing and waveforms you are working with, we may be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks @DanBoschen. I will gather up a bit more information and as soon as I have enough I'll post a comment. It's been a bit of a struggle to formally define the problem as the synthesiser, I've read, has all sorts of weird things stationary, cyclo-stationary, non-stationary, Alan variance etc. components. All I know at the moment is that the dominant phase noise sources are the reference clock and VCO which have power law phase noises i.e. $1/f^\alpha$.

Comment: And the only other thing is Gardner states that "But the
autocorrelation function of an $1/f^2$ process is nonstationary and the autocorrelation of an $1/f^3$ process is worse than nonstationary -- it does not even exist. Strictly speaking, then, the standard definition of spectral density is inapplicable to phase noise" and then he goes into defining some new meaning of spectrum of phase noise. Anyway, I think I'm all right with being able to just estimate the spectrum as the literature suggests.

Comment: Yes, be careful to not get bogged down in the theoretical that goes beyond practical implementation. In practice we make phase noise plots (a plot of the power spectral density) routinely using spectrum analyzers (as long as there is no dominant AM this approach is fine). There are tricks to avoid the non-stationary effects (notably drift). Email me boschen at loglin dot com if you want to discuss further, it goes beyond what can be answered here in a simple Q&A format.

Comment: All right. Yeah I think I've definitely fallen into a rabbit hole well above the pay grade of a student. Instead of trying to be accurate about the phase noise cancellation factor, I'm just going to quote it along with the assumption of WSS and then evaluate how this matches up with what I actually measure. I will definitely reach out to you if I get stuck. Thank you very much @DanBoschen.